# http response: 200 ok, but the page is blank

Tags: php, apache, http, server

I am facing this issue when trying to access a directory(index.php) in my website. The Response headers shows this:

```
content-type:text/html
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
```

But the page remains blank (content: 0).

I had similar issue while accessing other directories. But I could solve them. They were related file/directory permissions and errors were logged in the apache error log.

But for the present issue I dont see any errors in the error log. I'm not sure where to look for the issues.

Given that directory and its file contents are there,

What are the reasons for getting such a response? (an empty page with status 200)

Apart from using error log, where can I find the information related to the issue?

Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: **BLANK PAGES** ALWAYS means **Syntax** error in PHP. check you php_error_log or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file.

Comment: It does not solve the problem

Comment: Hello, could you share with us a piece of code ?

check :
- That you're under the good web server (apache, nginx)
- php extension is enabled.

You can also check the logs : `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`